# How do I import the ImageIOUtil and the PDFText2HTML classes from pdfBox

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

I`m trying to get a remote pdf file and perform some actions on it.
For this, I use PDFBox.
I can't get my hands on the tools package in order to import ImageIOUtil & PDFText2HTML

I added the pdfbox 2.0.6 via Maven dependency after searching the web I tried changing it to the 2.0.7 and 2.0.5

I used the location:

import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFText2HTML;

import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil;

Which are specified in the Javadoc here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/imageio/ImageIOUtil.html
https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/PDFText2HTML.html

But I get 'Cannot resolve symbol "tools"'

my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

my class imports:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil;
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFText2HTML;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use pdfbox-tools:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

And update all (also pdfbox and fontbox) to the current version, which is 2.0.15. Lots of bugs fixed (including a few security issues) and improvements made.